# File read in blocks gives ArgumentException

Tags: c#, file-io

Best explained with code:

```
long pieceLength = Math.Pow(2,18); //simplification
...
public void HashFile(string path)
{
    using (FileStream fin = File.OpenRead(path))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)pieceLength];
        int pieceNum = 0;
        long remaining = fin.Length;
        int done = 0;
        int offset = 0;
        while (remaining > 0)
        {
            while (done < pieceLength)
            {
                int toRead = (int)Math.Min(pieceLength, remaining);
                int read = fin.Read(buffer, offset, toRead);

                //if read == 0, EOF reached
                if (read == 0)
                    break;

                offset += read;
                done += read;
                remaining -= read;
            }
            HashPiece(buffer, pieceNum);
            done = 0;
            pieceNum++;
            buffer = new byte[(int)pieceLength];
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine if the file is smaller than `pieceLength` and only does the outer loop once. However, if the file is larger, it throws this at me:
This is in the `int read = fin.Read(buffer, offset, toRead);` line.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.
   at System.IO.FileStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
```

`done`, `buffer` DO get reinitialized properly. File is larger than 1 MB.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the real code, is "pieceLength" really mispelled "pieceLenght" in several places?

Comment: EDIT: Wait, huh? why isn't C# yelling?
Found out, had it missspelled everywhere :/

Comment: int offset = 0 inside the main loop.

Comment: This is not real code. `long pieceLength = Math.Pow(2, 18);` won't compile. Voting to close.

Comment: @Henk Holterman Simplification. is defined by constructor parameter. If this needed to be real code, I'd need a lot more space

Comment: @rene I need to hash the NEXT block, not the same :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, at least one problem is that you're not taking into account the "piece already read" when you work out how much to read. Try this:

```
int toRead = (int) Math.Min(pieceLenght - done, remaining);
```

And then also adjust where you're reading to within the buffer:

```
int read = fin.Read(buffer, done, toRead);
```

(as you're resetting `done` for the new buffer, but not `offset`).

Oh, and at that point `offset` is irrelevant, so remove it.

Then note djna's answer as well - consider the case where for whatever reason you read to the end of the file, but without `remaining` becoming zero. You may want to consider whether `remaining` is actually useful at all... why not just keep reading blocks until you get to the end of the stream?

Comment: Offset was indeed irrelevant, so thanks for that. Tested, works! Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

You don't adjust the value of "remaining" in this case

```
      if (read == 0)
                break;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [FileStream.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx) method's `Offset` and `Length` parameters relate to positions in the buffer, not to positions in the file.

Basically, this should fix it:

```
int read = fin.Read(buffer, 0, toRead);
```

Comment: No, the idea is to *fill* the buffer before hashing it.

Comment: See this line: byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)pieceLenght];

Comment: Yes, that's *outside* the inner while loop. The point is to loop around as many times as it takes to fill the buffer (which means reading with a non-zero offset if it ever takes more than one attempt) and then hash the buffer, recreate it and reset `done` to start at the beginning of the buffer again.

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but more than one attempt is not really efficient, hence the 'where are we' code. C# does not guarantee you read you want.